# How to install a package manually

Tags: package, microsoft-windows

I would like to install the projectile package manually since the repository is blocked by a firewall.

I have downloaded the file projectile.el from the [package homepage][1]  put it together with helm-projectile and helm-projectile into the folder `~/.emacs.d/projectile/'.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/projectile")
(require 'projectile)
```

The first line alone works, but with the second one emacs reports an error:

```
Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, dash
```

My current host system is windows.

---

**Edit**: package-install-file works wonders :)

This is what I had to do to get projectile installed:

```
M-x package-install-file RET path/to/dash.el

M-x package-install-file RET path/to/projectile.el
--> pkg-info-0.4 is unavailable

M-x package-install-file RET path/to/pkg-info.el
--> pkg-epl-0.4 is unavailable

M-x package-install-file RET path/to/epl.el

M-x package-install-file RET path/to/pkg-info.el
    In pkg-info-package-version:
    pkg-info.el:222:55:Warning: `epl-find-installed-package' is an obsolete
        function (as of 0.7); use `epl-find-installed-packages' instead.

M-x package-install-file RET path/to/projectile.el
```

Done.

Links

```
https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile
https://github.com/lunaryorn/pkg-info.el
https://github.com/cask/epl
```

Comment: Try installing the file with `M-x package-install-file` instead. That will sort out the directory and load path for you, as well as telling you about missing dependencies such as `dash`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're not using a package manager, you need to also manually install each package's dependencies. The error message tells you exactly which dependency you're missing.

You can see at the top of projectile.el:

```
(require 'thingatpt)
(require 'dash)
(require 'grep)           ; For `rgrep'
(require 'ibuffer)
(require 'ibuf-ext)
```

Some are included with Emacs. Some aren't. Here's [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el).

To see if you already have the libraries installed, you can do: `M-x find-library RET dash RET`